# Struggling with removing words based on pattern (text analysis in R)

Tags: r, text, analysis, stringr

I'm new to text analysis. I have been struggling with a particular problem in R this past week. I am trying to figure out how to remove or replace all variations of a word in a string. For example, if the string is:

```
test <- c("development", "develop", "developing", "developer", "apples", "kiwi")
```

I want the end output to be:

```
"apples", "kiwi"
```

So, basically, I'm trying to figure out how to remove or replace all words beginning with "^develop". I have tried using str_remove_all in the stringr package using this expression:

```
str_remove_all(test, "^dev")
```

But the end result was this:

```
"elopment", "elop", "eloping", "eloper", "apples", "kiwi"
```

It only removed parts of the word that matched the beginning expression "dev", whereas I want to remove the entire word if it matches the beginning of "dev".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grep with invert:

```
grep("^develop", test, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
## [1] "apples" "kiwi"
```

or negate grepl:

```
ok <- !grepl("^develop", test)
test[ok]
```

or remove `develop` and then retrieve those elements that have not changed:

```
test[sub("^develop", "", test) == test]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is much appreciated. My actual problem is filtering out words from a column in a dataframe, not from a vector. I adapted your code by converting the output of grep into a dataframe and assigning it to a new variable. It's not very elegant, but it works! I can't assign it to the original dataframe's column because of the error message that comes up from a difference in the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Filter(function(x) !any(grepl("develop", x)), test)

Answer (score 0):

via `stringr`, you can do:

```
stringr::str_subset(test, "^dev", negate = TRUE)
```